# Converting Boolean values inside array into if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

What is the best way to convert array values in to if statement. The array values should be compared by AND and the arrays by OR. I can do this using EVAL but looking for something other than EVAL.

```
$arr = Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => false
            [1] => true
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
            [1] => false
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => false
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => true,
            [1] => true,
            [2] => true
        )
)
```

I want to build comparison dynamically for if statement..

For example

`if( ($arr[0][0] && $arr[0][1]) || ($arr[1][0] && $arr[1][1]) .... and so on )`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What would you expect this set of arrays to turn into?

Comment: @cyberbit sorry for the incomplete question, have updated my post.

Comment: You could use `array_reduce()`, but a simple loop would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, function ($result, array $values) {
    return $result || array_reduce($values, function ($result, $value) {
        return $result && $value;
    }, true);
}, false);

if ($result) ...
```

One [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce) can elegantly do this for one array, you simply want to do it for two nested array levels.

Comment: Someone once said: *"Whether this is really a lot better than a simple foreach loop, aside from "but, but, functional programming...!", is debatable."* :p With a simple loop you can easily break and stop the loop as soon as one subArray results in TRUE.

Comment: Man, that is some really solid advice; must've been a wise, wise, headphones wearing man.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is generating a single boolean from values in an array. This is known as reduce operation. In php, we can do this with [`array_reduce(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).

```
array_reduce($input,
  function($prev, $item) {
    //Short-circuit if we already deduced it to be true
    if($prev) {
      return $prev;
    }

    //If one value is false, the entire thing is false
    foreach($item as $k => $v) {
      if(!$v) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    //All were true
    return true;
  }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. Never used array reduce before, learnt something new.